# Wordpress admin redirect working locally, but not on live

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wordpress-admin

I've got this snippet in my functions.php which redirects the user on successful login from the wp-admin dashboard to another admin page. It works fine on my local version, but when I upload this to my production server it isn't working at all, and on login it just continues to the dashboard like default.

I don't think it's a problem with the implementation, as the code is the same across both environments, so is their some kind of apache server config somewhere which could be preventing this redirect from happening?

```
function login_redirect_func( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    return admin_url('admin.php?page=acf-options-settings');
}
add_filter('login_redirect','login_redirect_func',10,3);
```

Comment: Please check is ACF enabled at your production server ?

Comment: Yep everything is enabled and otherwise 1:1 with the local version.